# How to plot date interval with event between in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with ID associated with a start, an end date and another corresponding to an event that occurred between the first 2.

I would like to plot on the ordinate the ID and on the abscissa
the dates with a line between the begining and the end of the period considered and a circle (or something else) for the event date.

I struggle since a few hours to find a suitable solution therefore any help would be highly appreciated !

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2018-11-11)

df <- data_frame(
  ID = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
  begin = seq(as.Date("2017-06-01"), as.Date("2017-08-31"), "1 month"),
  event = seq(as.Date("2018-06-01"), as.Date("2018-08-31"), "1 month"),
  end = seq(as.Date("2020-06-01"), as.Date("2020-08-31"), "1 month")
) 

ggplot(df, aes(x = begin, y = ID, group = ID)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()+
  xlab('Dates') +
  ylab('ID')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=ID, x=event)) + 
geom_point(color="red") + 
geom_segment(data=df, aes(x=begin, xend=end, y=ID, yend=ID))+
xlab('Dates') +
ylab('ID')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it: reshape the data into long format, then put ID on the y-axis and add a 2nd geom_points for the events:

```
df2 <- reshape2::melt(data = df, variable.name = 'Event', value.name = 'Date')

ggplot(df2, aes(x = Date, y = ID)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_line()+
   geom_point(data = df2 %>% filter(Event == 'event'), color='red', size = 2) +
   xlab('Dates') +
   ylab('ID')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2018-11-11)
# data_frame is sort of depreciated (The warning suggested me to use tibble instead)

df <- tibble(
  ID = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
  begin = seq(as.Date("2017-06-01"), as.Date("2017-08-31"), "1 month"),
  event = seq(as.Date("2018-06-01"), as.Date("2018-08-31"), "1 month"),
  end = seq(as.Date("2020-06-01"), as.Date("2020-08-31"), "1 month")
) 
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#df
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   ID    begin      event      end       
#   <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>    
# 1 A     2017-06-01 2018-06-01 2020-06-01
# 2 B     2017-07-01 2018-07-01 2020-07-01
# 3 C     2017-08-01 2018-08-01 2020-08-01
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
base <- ggplot(df, aes(x = begin, y = ID))

# add a duration between begin and end using a horizontal segment 
b_duration <- base + geom_segment(aes(x = begin, xend = end, y = ID, yend=ID), linetype = "dashed", color = "red")

# add a the event date using a circle (point)
b_duration + geom_point(aes(event), size=4, color = "cyan4") + theme_bw()
```

## Output

[image: duration_out]